# How can I increase the range of VirtualizingStackPanel in WP8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, virtualizingstackpanel

This questions is mainly for Windows Phone devs, but I guess any XAML technology is applicable.

My `VirtualizingStackPanel` works great and I can see the improvements in memory usage. However, the items I have in the `ListBox` are variable in height and can be quite complex to instantiate/bind.

When scrolling really fast, you start to see dead space while the panel is catching up. It seems to me that this issue could be fixed if the panel has the ability to render more items in advance.

At this point, I have a feeling it only renders 1 or 2 more items past the last visible item. Is there a way to increase this number? Can it render 5 items ahead?

If the answer is "no", is there a way to trick/hack it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instead of ListBox.

Comment: How exactly (give examples) would `LongListSelector` be able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deal with [virtualization mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)